# Is it possible to create a memory leak by using std::exception_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, exception, nested-exceptions

If I define an exception class

```
class Exception : public std::runtime_error
{
/*...*/
private:
    std::exception_ptr next;
    std::exception_ptr prev;
}
```

in which I refer to pending exceptions by `next` and new thrown exceptions while `this` is pending by `prev`, do the exception get freed after the exception is handled? The reason I'm asking is, that I once heard that `std::exception_ptr` is implemented in terms of reference counting which can lead to memory leaks, if there are reference cicles as I produced in this class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The reason I'm asking is, that I once heard that `std::exception_ptr` is implemented in terms of reference counting [...]

Not necessarily, but it could be. Paragraph 18.8.5/6 of the C++11 Standard mentions this in a note:

> ```
> typedef unspecified exception_ptr;
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> 6 [ *Note*: An implementation might use a reference-counted smart pointer as `exception_ptr`. —*end
>   note* ]

Therefore, you may not want to establish cycles of `exception_ptr`.